# Android studio getting stuck when run project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have update the google play service version to 7.+, this version is required for GoogleApiClient, After updating google play version when i run project it will take much time and stuck entire computer.

Please guide.

thanks

Comment: Try restarting studio or may be system.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use required Google API in project. What you need in your project.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
}
```

Note: Do not use complete google dependencies

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    }
```

Comment: I have already used required library then also getting stuck.